# Bootstrap Active Tab class not turning off when inactive

Tags: javascript, php, css, bootstrap-5

I am trying to adapt some bootstrap 5 functionality to a product image display page that displays a main image and then thumbnail images along with Lightbox main images below the main image.

the code sets the initial image tab to **active** so that on page load the initial image - img-0 tab is loaded by default.

The issue that then occurs is that when you click on one of the thumbnails to get the main image to load say img-1 for it sets the img-1 tab to active but it also leaves the initial img-0 as active as well.

after that any further clicks to change the main image work as expected.

I cannot see why the initial active class is not being removed.

The site is using jQuery 3.4.1, Bootstrap 5.2.2

im still new to Bootstrap, so is there somethign im missing or do i need to add some javascript to remove the initial active class from the img-0 tab?

```
            echo "<div class='single-product-tab-content'>";
                ## DISPLAY MAIN IMAGE ##
                if (count($image_array) > 1) 
                {           
//                  echo "<!-- Tab panes -->";
                    echo "<div class='tab-content'>";
                        foreach ($image_array as $key => $data) 
                        {
                            if (file_exists($site['url']['path'].$site['path']['product']['full'].$data['productImageFile'])) 
                            {
                                if($key == 0)
                                {
                                    echo "<div role='tabpanel' class='tab-pane active' id='img-".$key."'>";
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    echo "<div role='tabpanel' class='tab-pane' id='img-".$key."'>";
                                }
                                    echo "<a href='".$site['url']['full'].$site['path']['product']['full'].$data['productImageFile']."'  data-lightbox='lightbox[".$value['productId']."]' data-title='".$image_array[$site['url']['decode']['photo']]['productImageTitle']."'>";
                                        echo "<img src='".$site['url']['full'].$site['path']['product']['full'].$data['productImageFile']."' alt='".$data['productImageDescription']."' title='".$data['productImageTitle']."' />";
                                        echo "<span class='view-full-screen' ><i class='fa-solid fa-arrows-maximize'></i> view full screen</span>";
                                    echo "</a>";
                                echo "</div>";
                            }
                        }
                    echo "</div>";
                }
                
                ## DISPLAY IMAGE THUMBNAILS ##
                if (count($image_array) > 1) 
                {
                    echo "<ul class='nav'>";
                        foreach ($image_array as $key => $data) 
                        {
                            if (file_exists($site['url']['path'].$site['path']['product']['thumb'].$data['productImageFile'])) 
                            {
                                    if($key == 0)
                                    {
                                        echo "<li class='active'>";
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        echo "<li>";
                                    }
                                    echo"<a href='#img-".$key."'  data-bs-toggle='tab'><img src='".$site['url']['full'].$site['path']['product']['thumb'].$data['productImageFile']."' alt='".$data['productImageDescription']."' title='".$data['productImageTitle']."' /></a></li>";
                            }
                        }
                    echo "</ul>";                   
                }               

            echo "</div>";
```

here is the code that is generated:

```
<div class="single-product-tab-content">
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane active show" id="img-0">
            <a href="https://www.mywebsite.com/content/product/full/Tuberous_Begonia_Tubers___Hanging_Basket_Tubers___Mixed-971-941.jpg" data-lightbox="lightbox[941]" data-title="Tuberous Begonia Tubers   Hanging Basket Tubers   Mixed">
                <img src="https://www.mywebsite.com/content/product/full/Tuberous_Begonia_Tubers___Hanging_Basket_Tubers___Mixed-971-941.jpg" alt="Tuberous Begonia Tubers   Hanging Basket Tubers   Mixed" title="Tuberous Begonia Tubers   Hanging Basket Tubers   Mixed">
                <span class="view-full-screen"><i class="fa-solid fa-arrows-maximize"></i> view full screen</span>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane" id="img-1">
            <a href="https://www.mywebsite.com/content/product/full/Tuberous_Begonia_Tubers___Hanging_Basket_Tubers___Mixed-972-941.jpg" data-lightbox="lightbox[941]" data-title="Tuberous Begonia Tubers   Hanging Basket Tubers   Mixed">
                <img src="https://www.mywebsite.com/content/product/full/Tuberous_Begonia_Tubers___Hanging_Basket_Tubers___Mixed-972-941.jpg" alt="Tuberous Begonia Tubers   Hanging Basket Tubers   Mixed" title="Tuberous Begonia Tubers   Hanging Basket Tubers   Mixed">
                <span class="view-full-screen"><i class="fa-solid fa-arrows-maximize"></i> view full screen</span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav" role="tablist">
        <li class="active">
            <a href="#img-0" data-bs-toggle="tab" aria-selected="true" role="tab" class="active">
                <img src="https://www.mywebsite.com/content/product/thumb/Tuberous_Begonia_Tubers___Hanging_Basket_Tubers___Mixed-971-941.jpg" alt="Tuberous Begonia Tubers   Hanging Basket Tubers   Mixed" title="Tuberous Begonia Tubers   Hanging Basket Tubers   Mixed">
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#img-1" data-bs-toggle="tab" aria-selected="false" role="tab" class="" tabindex="-1">
                <img src="https://www.mywebsite.com/content/product/thumb/Tuberous_Begonia_Tubers___Hanging_Basket_Tubers___Mixed-972-941.jpg" alt="Tuberous Begonia Tubers   Hanging Basket Tubers   Mixed" title="Tuberous Begonia Tubers   Hanging Basket Tubers   Mixed">
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The error only occurs on the initial page load or if the page is reloaded..ie CTRL F5 etc

The issue can be seen in these screenshots:

**wrong:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/iNmtV.jpg

**correct:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/c241L.jpg

**correct:** https://i.stack.imgur.com/6jF9b.jpg

here is the template theme i was trying to base my code from: https://htmldemo.net/shopick-v1/shopick/single-product.html

Comment: Not sure if this is supposed to work properly based on the `href` attribute, all the examples under https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/navs-tabs/#using-data-attributes appear to use the `data-bs-target` attribute to link the nav item with the corresponding tab.

Comment: hrrrm i was basing it from a few templates id seen on various theme sites such as this one on envato:

https://htmldemo.net/shopick-v1/shopick/single-product.html

Comment: Not every example you find must necessarily rely on attributes to _automatically_ trigger the functionality, it might also use explicitly written JavaScript function calls. Use the examples in the official bootstrap documentation as your guideline, rather than 3rd-party sources.